# Apariencia diferente de botones en safari iOS

Tags: css, ios, css3, safari

Tengo un botón pero en iOS Safari se ve diferente. He probado con este codigo `-webkit-appearance: none;` y no me funciona.

Éste es el CSS del botón (también en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3ryvhwf/)):

```css
button {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3fc2f0;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(#3fc2f0, #3fc2f0);*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
  -moz-border-radius: 24px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #19748f;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #19748f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #19748f;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button>Comprar</button>
```

Que se ve así en diferentes navegadores (el tamaño es igual, el problema es el borde diferente):

[image: Incluso con el mismo css se ven diferentes en el mismo ipad]

Incluso con el mismo CSS se ven diferentes en el mismo iPad. ¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Quizás te sirva usar `border: none`

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```
 button{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

En caso de que no te funcionara, y a pesar de no ser una buena práctica, puedes añadirle (!important), quedando así:

```
button{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    }
```

Espero que te sirva ;)

Answer (score 1):

En tu `CSS` no estás definiendo la propiedad `border` entonces el navegador se encarga de poner el estilo de bordes por default.

Estoy casi seguro (debido a que no tengo safari) que si añades `border: 1px solid #CCC;` a tu `CSS` solo como prueba, los bordes se verán iguales.

```
button {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #3fc2f0;
   /*background-image: linear-gradient(#3fc2f0, #3fc2f0);*/
   -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
   -moz-border-radius: 24px;
   border-radius: 24px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #19748f;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #19748f;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #19748f;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 16px;
   position: relative;

    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```